# Pycharm not finding executable for chromedriver for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I install chromedriver through my `package.json` file and it gets installed in my `npm_modules` folder. Then I add it to the `PATH` of executables, when running through terminal tests are passing.
When running the same command in pycharm, says that it cannot find the executable:
`WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Im guessing that I have to set it up in a specific way in pycharm.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, since i am installing chromedriver through NPM my path to the executable ends up something like this:
`node_modules/geckodriver/bin/`
So I add that to the systems `PATH` at the entry point of my app:

```
import os
path = '{}:{}'.format(os.getenv('PATH'),
                      os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'node_modules', 'chromedriver', 'bin')
os.environ["PATH"] = path
```

And then you need to run PyCharm as super user, otherwise trying to run tests will throw a `127` status code when trying to run the executable.
So just do (for Mac):

`sudo /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm`

And you will be able to run and debug tests.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by specifying the path to chromedriver when calling webdriver.Chrome like this in my code;

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('<path_to>/chromedriver')
```

PyCharm now has no problem locating and executing the driver.

Note: Found this solution in [JetBrains PyCharm community support site.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000255250-Selenium-ChromeDriver-path-issue-with-PyCharm)

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by following approach.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'Path_to_chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specific custom PATH variable for chromedriver to PyCharm debug configuration environment variables.

Comment: If you answer a question that is more than two years old, please give a few more details like filenames and params that you expect the OP to change.